# SSL Error When Connecting to HTTPS URL Using Node.js Request-Promise Library

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, postman, request-promise

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const https = require('https');

const agentOptions = {
                    host: 'localhost',
                    port: 443,
                    path: '/',
                    rejectUnauthorized: false,
                    secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_method'
                };

                const agent = new https.Agent(agentOptions);

                const options = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'https://sandbox-us-api.experian.com/consumerservices/social-search/v1/social-search',
                    headers: request.headers,
                    body: request.payload,
                    json: true,
                    agent: agent
                };

const res = await rp(options);
```

**Upon running this in Postman using the URL: http://localhost:443/experian/social_search/get , I get an error of:**

> Error: write EPROTO 105840:error:1408F10B:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version
>   number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:332:

**The Experian Third Party API does not use self signed. And I was able to run the sandbox URL in the Postman.**

Anyone have any ideas what is the problem?

Comment: Have you found the solution? Getting the same error here :(

Comment: I have the same error on Node 12.6.1.

Comment: Me too, getting same error. Any solution ?

Comment: What was your solution?